# Mysql query to convert table from long format to wide format

Tags: mysql

I have a table called ContactAttrbiutes which contains a list of each contacts' attributes. The kind of data stored for these contacts include: Title, Forename, Surname telephone number etc.

**Current Table**

```
+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
| attributeId | ContactId | AttributeValue               |
+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
|           1 |         5 | Lady                         |
|           2 |         5 | Elizabeth                    |
|           3 |         5 | E                            |
|           4 |         5 | Anson                        |
|           5 |         5 |                              |
|           6 |         5 |                              |
|           7 |         5 |                              |
|           8 |         5 |                              |
|          10 |         5 | 0207 72776                   |
|          11 |         5 |                              |
|          12 |         5 | 0207 22996                   |
|          13 |         5 | 0207 72761                   |
|          14 |         5 |                              |
|          15 |         5 |                              |
|          60 |         5 | Lloyds                       |
|          61 |         5 |                              |
|           1 |        10 | Mr                           |
|           2 |        10 | John                         |
|           3 |        10 | J C                          |
|           4 |        10 | Beveridge                    |
|           5 |        10 | Esq QC                       |
|           6 |        10 | Retired                      |
|           7 |        10 |                              |
|           8 |        10 |                              |
|          10 |        10 | 0207 930                     |
|          11 |        10 |                              |
|          12 |        10 |                              |
|          13 |        10 | 0207 930                     |
|          14 |        10 |                              |
|          15 |        10 |                              |
|          60 |        10 |                              |
|          61 |        10 |                              |
+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+
```

However I would like to run a query to create a table that looks like...

**New Table**

```
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| ContactId | AttributeValue_Title | AttributeValue_ForeName |AttributeValue_Initial | AttributeValue_Surname |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 5         | Lady                 | Elizabeth               | E                     |  Anson                 |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| 10        | Mr                   | John                    | J C                   | Beveridge              |
+-----------+----------------------+-------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
```

I am sure there is a very simple answer but I have spent hours looking. Can anyone help?

The above is only a small extract of my table, I have 750,000 contacts. In addition I would like the final table to have more columns than I have described above but they will come from different Attributes with the existing table.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: attribute ID links to?

Comment: AttributeId links to another table called attributes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
    SELECT ContactId , 
 max(CASE when attributeId = 1 then AttributeValue end) as AttributeValue_Title ,
 max(CASE when attributeId = 2 then AttributeValue end )as AttributeValue_ForeName ,
 max(CASE when attributeId = 3 then AttributeValue end )as AttributeValue_Initial ,
 max(CASE when attributeId = 4 then AttributeValue end) as AttributeValue_Surname  
 from Table1 
 group by ContactId
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76de3/16)

- if you want to make your result more longer for other `attributeId` then just add a case statment as in the code.

Comment: This solution was perfect although returns the results slightly slower than the solution from @RandomSeed. However I wanted to understand and use 'Case'. Many thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    t_title.AttributeValue AS title,
    t_name.AttributeValue AS name,
    ...
FROM the_table AS t_title
JOIN the_table AS t_firstname USING(contact_id)
JOIN ...
WHERE
    t_title.attributeId = 1 AND
    t_firstname.attributeId = 2 AND
    ...
```

[EAV "model" is an antipattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) in most cases. Are you really going to have a variable number of attributes? If yes, then no-SQL solution might be more appropriate than a relational database.

Comment: The attributes I want to query will be specific (i.e. they will not vary). The solution you have recommended does return the results faster then the solution given by @echo_Me. Thank you for your help! :).